# How to pass parameters in an async api thunk call

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Hi I am trying to pass a parameter for the post method in an api call in a redux thunk middleware. But this is not invoking an action. Could someone have a look at the code and tell what mistake i am doing:

```
import API from "../../_metronic/utils/api";

let FetchActions = async (id,dispatch) => {
  await API.post("companies/",id)
    .then(res => dispatch({ type: "FETCH_COMPANIES", payload: res.data }))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

export default FetchActions;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: dispatch is not a function
    at fetchAction.js:6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
import API from "../../_metronic/utils/api";

let FetchActions = id => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  await API.post("companies/",id)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({ type: "FETCH_COMPANIES", payload: res.data })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    });
};

export default FetchActions;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing wrong with the syntax as `redux-thunk` needs a `callback function` to return from the method.
Another thing is if you are using `await` you don't need to have `.then` and `.catch`, instead, you should wrap this code in the `try-catch` block.

The below code should work for you.

```
import API from "../../_metronic/utils/api";

let FetchActions = async (id) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
      try {
       const res = await API.post("companies/",id);
       dispatch({ type: "FETCH_COMPANIES", payload: res.data })
      } catch(err) {
         console.log(err)
      }
 }
};

export default FetchActions;
```

Read more about the action creators in `redux-thunk` [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#motivation).